# Should I use design patterns or an algorithm? And what's the difference?

Tags: design-patterns

I have been given a task of finding the permutations of the letters of a given word. For example, if the given word is *like* then possible answers are *liek*, *lkie*, and so on. This can be implemented in any language, but the rule is not to use any built-in functions/API to find the combinations.

We know that design patterns are for solving any problem with a given solution. For example, Information Expert is a design pattern. Is there any design pattern for finding combinations? Or will design patterns not suit for this situation? Will I have to learn a good algorithm for finding the solution? In that case, what’s the difference between an algorithm and a design pattern? Both try to solve the problem in a good, efficient way, right?

Please correct me if I’m wrong!

Comment: Are you just making random changes to the string? Finding all the possible combinations of the letters? The problem is not very well specified, IMO...

Comment: I'm just swapping the first two letters and check in the answer list(which hold answers) for duplicates, if they found already then i will skip,then i will swap the next second and third letter and keep on goes untill i found the answer. The loop will get exit if it done all the combinations, that is before entering the loop i will found the number of possible of combinations which then act as upper bound for my loop!

Comment: That sounds.... expensive!

Comment: The number of combinations is n! for a n letter word assuming all letters are unique.  Handling duplicate letters could be a major pain with this kind of problem but this does seem like a common Combinatorics problem to my mind.

Comment: You say you're looking for combinations, but your example is of finding permutations. Also, the number of combinations for a string of length n containing no duplicate letters is not n!; the number of permutations is.

Comment: The answer is definitely in Cracking the Coding Interview.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An algorithm is [an effective method expressed as a finite list of well-defined instructions for calculating a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm). A design pattern is [a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29).

You have a function you need to calculate (the combinations of letters from a list of letters), which means you definitely need an algorithm. Once you have an algorithm, you may find that you can implement it using a reusable solution, in which case you may be able to employ a design pattern. However you cannot apply a reusable solution before you know what the solution ought to look like, so solve your problem first.

Comment: +1 for However you cannot apply a reusable solution before you know what the solution ought to look like, so solve your problem first.